# AWS Elastic Bean Stalk, Error 403 Forbidden "You don't have permission to access this resource."

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to upload my PHP web app on AWS Elastic Bean Stalk, this was working fine about a month ago. But now when I upload my web app and visit it and go to a folder (eg. /images) it throws an error "403 Forbidden, you don't have permission to access this resource."

I'm guessing I need to somehow allow permissions to my AWS Elastic Bean Stalk, but I don't know how to get started. Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When you are using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, automatically EC2 instances are configured. You can access to EC2 and see your actual configuration. See the inbound rules and permit the access from anywhere.

Take into account that create a Load Balancer is really useful, it permits to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk + AWS CloudFront to use https instance of http.